# Get both the headers and the body of a curl response in two separated variables?

Tags: bash, curl

I am looking for a way to make ONE curl call and get to variables from it: one with the headers and another with the response body.

I've found several questions asking about how to separate headers from body, but people seems only interested in one of them. I need both headers and body.

I cannot use an external file to store the body (thus using -o $file is not an option).

I can use

```
headers=$(curl -D /dev/stdout $URL)
```

to get the headers into one variable, but how can I redirect the output to another variable?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
head=true
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    if $head; then 
        if [[ -z $line ]]; then 
            head=false
        else
            headers+=("$line")
        fi
    else
        body+=("$line")
    fi
done < <(curl -sD - "$url" | sed 's/\r$//')
printf "%s\n" "${headers[@]}"
echo ===
printf "%s\n" "${body[@]}"
```

To join the elements of an array into a single scalar variable:

```
the_body=$( IFS=$'\n'; echo "$body[*]" )
```

---

In `bash` 4.3, you can use named references to simplify switching from "header" mode to "body" mode:

```
declare -n section=headers
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line = $'\r' ]]; then
        declare -n section=body
    fi
    section+=("$line")
done < <(curl -sD - "$url")
```

---

For some reason, glenn jackman's answer did not catch the body part of the response. I had to separate the curl request into another command expansion and then enclose it in double quotes. Then I did not use arrays, but simply concatenated values to the variables. This works for me:

```
output=$(curl -si -d "" --request POST https://$url)

head=true
while read -r line; do 
    if $head; then 
        if [[ $line = $'\r' ]]; then
            head=false
        else
            header="$header"$'\n'"$line"
        fi
    else
        body="$body"$'\n'"$line"
    fi
done < <(echo "$output")
```

Thank you, Glenn!

Comment: I was trying to get something like this working, but I don't understand why the `cat` doesn't continue reading from where the `sed` left off: `{ h=$(sed '/^$/q'); b=$(cat); } < <(curl -si $url)`

Comment: That's a good question. Keep in mind that curl returns the headers with `\r\n` line endings, so `/^$/` won't signify the end of the headers, you'll have to use `/^\r$/` or strip out the carriage returns like I do in my answer. But even correcting for that, I don't know why sed eats all the input after it's supposed to quit.

Comment: Although `sed` processes its input one line at a time, that doesn't mean it *reads* only one line at a time from its standard input. It may read `N` lines, with the other `N-1` being buffered until `sed` is done with the first line. If `sed` exits before processing the rest of the buffer, those lines are not "restored" to standard input  for the next command (in this case `cat`) to consume.

Comment: @ooga, looks like you'll have to replace that sed command with a shell while-read loop.

Comment: The plug I added for `bash` 4.3 also shows how to get rid of `sed` altogether, by comparing `$line` to a fixed string representing an "empty" `\r`-terminated line.

Comment: That is very tidy. It leaves the carriage returns in the data which may be troublesome later on, but that's straightforward to deal with.

Comment: Looks like this might work (-u option to sed means "unbuffered"): `{ h=$(sed -u '/^\r$/q'); b=$(cat); } < <(curl -si $url)`

Comment: Thank you, but it seems to not get the body part of the response. Can you please explain your solution? Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel, good job figuring it out. Question: did you notice I pass the output of curl into sed to remove the carriage returns? That may explain your observations. Advice: use a here-string `<<< "$output"` instead of the process substitution `< <(echo "$output")`

Comment: This is a great way to parse all the header information.

Answer (score 15):

I would like to share a way to parse curl response without any external program, bash only.

First, get the response of a curl request passing `-sw "%{http_code}"`.

```
res=$(curl -sw "%{http_code}" $url)
```

The result will be a string containing the body followed by the http code.

Then, get the http code:

```
http_code="${res:${#res}-3}"
```

And the body:

```
if [ ${#res} -eq 3 ]; then
  body=""
else
  body="${res:0:${#res}-3}"
fi
```

Note that if the length of http_code and response are equal (length 3), body is empty. Else, just strip out the http code and you get the body.

Comment: This is a more simple way to check the status_code only. However the original question was about parsing the header fields, I like this solution and used it in my library. ( https://bitbucket.org/kisp/bash_lib/src/ccd542aa361bf66458195d71a93aeb475100c832/http_get.sh?fileviewer=file-view-default ) thanks for the tip.

Comment: @kisp Glad to know you are using it. Please, be aware that I did not tested it very much, although it should work well since it is very simple.

Comment: I know this does not strictly answer the question but it is _very_ useful nonetheless (and close enough to be upvoted).

Comment: Easier method: ```response_code=${response: -3}
echo $response_code
connection_string=${response:0: -3}
echo $connection_string```

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by [0x10203040's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37072904/10366669), the following script puts the response headers into one variable, and the response body into another.  I'm a noob at this, so I've probably done *something* unwise/inefficient; feel free to offer suggestions for improvement.

```sh
# Perform the request:
# - Optionally suppress progress output from the terminal (-s switch).
# - Include the response headers in the output (-i switch).
# - Append the response header/body sizes to the output (-w argument).
URL="https://example.com/"
response=$(curl -si -w "\n%{size_header},%{size_download}" "${URL}")

# Extract the response header size.
headerSize=$(sed -n '$ s/^\([0-9]*\),.*$/\1/ p' <<< "${response}")

# Extract the response body size.
bodySize=$(sed -n '$ s/^.*,\([0-9]*\)$/\1/ p' <<< "${response}")

# Extract the response headers.
headers="${response:0:${headerSize}}"

# Extract the response body.
body="${response:${headerSize}:${bodySize}}"
```

## Explanation

### [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) – transfer a URL

#### [`--include`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-i)

Use the `--include (-i)` option to include the response headers in `curl`'s stdout, ahead of the response body.

#### [`--write-out`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-w)

Use the `--write-out (-w)` option to append some useful things onto the end of `curl`'s stdout:

- `\n` (a new line so `sed` can process the header/body sizes separately)
- `%{size_header},%{size_download}` (response header size and response body size, respectively, separated by a comma or something)

```sh
... -w "\n%{size_header},%{size_download}" ...
```

#### [`--silent`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-s) (optional)

Depending on the type of request, `curl` might output progress updates to stderr in your terminal.  It won't affect stdout, but you can suppress it using the `--silent (-s)` option.  (See [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#PROGRESS) for more information.)

---

Use [command substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) (`$(...)`) to execute `curl` in a subshell and get its entire stdout (response headers and body) into a single `$response` variable for now; we will extract the headers and the body from it separately after the fact.

```sh
response=$(curl -si -w "\n%{size_header},%{size_download}" "${URL}")
```

`$response` should contain something like this:

```
HTTP/2 200 
age: 384681
cache-control: max-age=604800
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Tue, 03 Nov 2020 06:54:45 GMT
etag: "3147526947+ident"
expires: Tue, 10 Nov 2020 06:54:45 GMT
last-modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT
server: ECS (ord/4CB8)
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-cache: HIT
content-length: 1256

<!doctype html>
<html>
...
</html>

331,1256
```

Notice the header,body sizes alone on the last line, thanks to the `-w` option.

### [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) – stream editor

```sh
... sed -n '$ s/^\([0-9]*\),.*$/\1/ p' ...
... sed -n '$ s/^.*,\([0-9]*\)$/\1/ p' ...
```

#### [`--silent`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options)

Use the `--silent` (`--quiet`/`-n`) option to prevent `sed` from outputting every line that passes through it.

#### [`$` address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Numeric-Addresses)

Use the `$` address to process only the last line (the header/body sizes).

#### [`s` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)

Use the `s` command to perform a substitution.  Basically, use a regex to match the line containing the header/body sizes, then substitute that entire line with just the header size or the body size, then output the substituted line, i.e. output just the header size, or just the body size:

1. `s`: the substitution command.
2. `/`: begin the regex search pattern.
3. `^`: match the beginning of the line.
4. `\(`: begin a group to contain the header size.
5. `[0-9]*`: match 0 or more digits (i.e. the header size).
6. `\)`: finish the group containing the header size.
7. `,.*`: after the group, match a comma, followed by 0 or more of any character (to match the rest of the line).
8. `$`: match the end of the line.
9. `/`: finish the regex search pattern; begin the replacement pattern.
10. `\1`: replace the matched text (i.e. the entire line) with the group (i.e. just header size).
11. `/`: end the replacement pattern.

```
s/^\([0-9]*\),.*$/\1/
```

Above is for the header size, which is *before* the comma; below is similar for the body size, which is *after* the comma.

```
s/^.*,\([0-9]*\)$/\1/
```

#### [`p` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Common-Commands)

Use the `p` command to output the processed line despite the `-n` option.

---

Use a "[here-string](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection#here_strings)" (`<<<`) to pass `curl`'s `$response` to `sed`'s stdin.  Since we suppressed `sed`'s output (`-n`), processed only the last line (`$`), substituted (`s/...`) the entire line with either the header size or the body size, then output it (`p`), `sed` should output just those, respectively.  And again use [command substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) to put them into `$headerSize` and `$bodySize` variables.

```sh
headerSize=$(sed -n '$ s/^\([0-9]*\),.*$/\1/ p' <<< "${response}")
bodySize=$(sed -n '$ s/^.*,\([0-9]*\)$/\1/ p' <<< "${response}")
```

---

Finally, now knowing the size of the header and body, use [parameter substring expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_expansion) (`${variable:offset:length}`) to pull the response headers and response body into separate `$headers` and `$body` variables.

```sh
headers="${response:0:${headerSize}}"
body="${response:${headerSize}:${bodySize}}"
```

### Troubleshooting

Works for me in macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 using the following:

- GNU bash version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)
- curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.0) libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.0.20 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.0

If you're counting characters, the following things tripped me up:

- HTTP headers have CR+LF for EOLs, so that's 2 bytes for each EOL.
- Some code editors (such as Visual Studio Code) will summarily normalize line endings, so what ends up in your editor might not be exactly the same as what `curl` actually output.
- Some character encodings (such as UTF-8, etc.) use multiple bytes to represent certain individual characters, so there might be fewer *characters* than the size of the header/body in *bytes*; similarly for control characters/other non-printing characters, etc. that might not appear in text/code editors.

So it might be better to use a hex-editor rather than a text-editor for troubleshooting.