# Is it possible to save curl -o to a variable in Bash?

Tags: bash, curl

This command:

```
http_status=$(curl -s -o output.txt -w %{http_code} "https://link.com")
```

Will save the HTTP status code to the variable http_status and the body to the file output.txt. Is it possible to save the body in a variable without first outputting it to a file while I at the same time save the status code in the variable http_status?

I'm guessing I can't just replace the filename with a variable.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852524/get-both-the-headers-and-the-body-of-a-curl-response-in-two-separated-variables) so I know the basic idea of saving the body and header in two variables is possible. But I was wondering if you could use -o flag of CURL to solve it with less code.